# "Open With" using CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Let's say I have a program that I want to open. I can open it using batch by running this:

```
@echo off
start "" "C:\Program.exe"
```

Is there a way to tell batch that I want to open the file using a program such as notepad? Something along the lines of this:

```
start "" "C:\Program.exe" >notepad.exe
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure, but you can use

```
@echo off
notepad.exe "C:\Program.exe"
```

You can use every program that supports "Open With" (every good program supports it)
The File-Path will be passed to the program, so it knows your file.

Comment: It's a Windows feature, not a program feature. Other than that, this is the best answer he's going to get other than "change the default program that the file opens with," and that is more of an answer for SuperUser.

Comment: @SomethingDark it depends on the program accepting the files as the first parameters by default (if there's no setting in the registry)

Comment: That's not "open with", it's just the program taking command-line options.

Answer (score 0):

I used following code.

```
@echo off
start  notepad C:\Program.exe
```

Make sure to set the path to **notepad.exe**.

You must need double quotes only if you have spaces in the path to your file.

```
@echo off
start  notepad "C:\My Program.exe"
```

Comment: This is just duplicating the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use openwith command:

```
...>openwith "C:program.exe"
```

this command opens "Open with" window and you can choose witch program "program.exe" should be opened or run with.

you can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-gppref/9e5390cc-0aa8-4445-86ec-064edce958c9) in Microsoft docs about this command.

Comment: OpenWith is not a program, nor a command built into the command-prompt. The specified link is a *protocol* that can't be invoked as stated in the post.

Comment: @Synetech When right-clicking on a file and selecting "Open With" / "Choose another app", the dialog showing a list of programs is indeed a program itself. You can find it in `C:\Windows\System32\OpenWith.exe`. That `openwith.exe` is used in this answer and will *always* ask which program to use, even for known file types. Of course the link in the answer is irrelevant here.